# How can I get number of deleted records?

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure which deletes certain records. I need to get the number of deleted records.

I tried to do it like this:

```
DELETE FROM OperationsV1.dbo.Files WHERE FileID = @FileID   
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT AS DELETED;
```

But DELETED is shown as 0, though the appropriate records are deleted. I tried SET NOCOUNT OFF; without success. Could you please help?
Thanks.

Comment: What do you do with the value you get from `@@ROWCOUNT` ? Do you want to return it?? You might need to use `DECLARE @DeleteCnt INT;  SELECT @DeleteCnt = @@ROWCOUNT` to capture the value into a variable which you can then return or insert into an audit table or something

Comment: It worked for me thx!!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

That should work fine. The setting of `NOCOUNT` is irrelevant. This only affects the `n rows affected` information sent back to the client and has no effect on the workings of  `@@ROWCOUNT`.

Do you have any statements between the two that you have shown? `@@ROWCOUNT` is reset after every statement so you must retrieve the value immediately with no intervening statements.

Comment: No, there is nothing between.

Comment: How are you testing this? In Management Studio?

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake. I put SELECT @@ROWCOUNT AS DELETED; after a wrong Delete statement.

Answer (score 5):

I use this code snippet when debugging stored procedures to verify counts after operations, such as a delete:

```
DECLARE @Msg varchar(30)
...
SELECT @Msg = CAST(@@ROWCOUNT AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' rows affected'
RAISERROR (@Msg, 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT
```

Answer (score -7):

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT @before:=(SELECT count(*) FROM OperationsV1.dbo.Files);
DELETE FROM OperationsV1.dbo.Files WHERE FileID = @FileID;
SELECT @after:=(SELECT count(*) FROM OperationsV1.dbo.Files);
COMMIT;
SELECT @before-@after AS DELETED;
```

I don't know about SQL server, but in MySQL `SELECT count(*) FROM ...` is an extremely cheap operation.

Comment: Thanks Eugen. Let's see if anybody can explain why @@ROWCOUNT doesn't work for me. I will use your solution if nobody helps on @@ROWCOUNT.

Comment: At the default transaction isolation level, this would still allow another delete to change the count halfway this query.

Comment: @David - Don't use this. This is expensive and has race conditions.

Comment: This question is clearly tagged for `sql-server`. Resisting the urge to downvote this as it uses MySQL-specific syntax.

Comment: Agree with @MartinSmith. Minus one for 'extremely cheap operation'.

Comment: Downvoted because OP tagged as sql-server and not mySql.