# How can I check if the input is in database?

Tags: java

my JFrame cancels the ticket.
I let the user input the ticket id which is stored in the database and phone number and that happened but **my question is how can I check if this ticket is in a database or not**! please if you know

here is my code

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
  String Ticket_ID=CardNumberTF.getText();
    String phone=CardNumberTF1.getText();
 if(Ticket_ID.isEmpty()&& phone.isEmpty()){
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please full the fields ");}

 else if(Ticket_ID.isEmpty() || phone.isEmpty()){
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please full the empty field  ");}

try{
 con=DriverManager.getConnection(URL,"iau","iau");
 prepared=con.prepareStatement("Delete from BOOKING_INFO WHERE ID_TICKET=? AND PHONE_NUM=?");
 prepared.setString(1,Ticket_ID );
 prepared.setString(2,phone );
 prepared.executeUpdate();
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
 "deleted","delete",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
       }catch(SQLException ex){
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
     "we don't have this ticket id", "Failed",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
       System.out.print(ex);
    }

 private void connect(){
        try{
            con=DriverManager.getConnection(URL, "iau","iau");
        }catch(SQLException ex){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex);
        }}
```

Comment: Try to read it from the database. But you shouldn't check if it exists before you delete it, because even if it does, someone else might delete it, so by the time you try to delete it, it might not exist anymore.

Comment: Instead of letting the user enter the ticket ID, you could query the database and present all valid IDs in a list box for the user to select from. Still, someone could delete a ticket between the time you populate the list and the user tries to delete, though. That said, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577632/how-can-i-get-number-of-deleted-records

Answer (score 1):

Same as you are doing your `delete statement` `prepared=con.prepareStatement("Delete from BOOKING_INFO WHERE ID_TICKET=? AND PHONE_NUM=?");`, for example:

```
boolean ticketExists = false;
prepared=con.prepareStatement("Select * BOOKING_INFO WHERE ID_TICKET=? AND PHONE_NUM=?");
prepared.setString(1, Ticket_ID);
prepared.setString(2, phone)

ResultSet result = prepared.executeQuery();

while (result.next()) {
   // this means that there is ticket, because the result is NOT NULL
   // set ticketExists to true
   ticketExists = true;
}
```

`

Comment: you mean i should write select instead of delete query?

Comment: It depends what you want to achieve, but my business logic would be: first select it and check if it exists in database, if not, insert it in database, otherwise if it already exists in database: notify the user!